# IF statement in mysql JOIN - Adding multiple conditions if condition success

Tags: mysql

Here is the case:-

I want to join 2 tables. Lets say table `a` and `b`

```
SELECT * 
FROM a 
JOIN b ON a.id = b.id AND b.status = '1'
```

Here is the problem:

```
b.status = '1'
```

should only be added when

```
b.stage in (1, 3, 5, 6, 8)
```

How can I add such condition in `ON` clause ?

Like

```
ON a.id = b.id 
CASE
   IF (b.stage in (1, 3, 5, 6, 8))
THEN
   AND b.status = '1'
END
```

Comment: well, you can always use boolean logic to bypass a clause like this: `AND ( b.status = '1' OR b.stage NOT IN (1, 3, 5, 6, 8) )`

Comment: Slight changes in question.

Answer (score 5):

Your condition is logically the same as "*either* stage is not in the list *or* status is 1":

```
SELECT * 
FROM a 
JOIN b ON a.id = b.id 
    AND (b.stage not in (1, 3, 5, 6, 8) OR b.status = '1')
```

Comment: I can not put `not in` there. Because I want (1, 3, 5, 6, 8) record also.

Comment: @Sahal its correct, you want to have those included, but only if they have b.status = 1. Its a "combined clause" and matches your requirements from your question

Comment: Can you be more specific? This query is exactly what you asked for. It is logically identical to only testing for `status=1` if `stage` is in the list.

Comment: Slight changes in question.

Comment: @Najzero I did some miss typo in my question. Please read after the text `LIKE`

Comment: Even after your slight changes, this query is what you want. Trust me. I've been coding SQL for 25 years *and* I studied Formal Logic as a subject in my degree.

Comment: @Sahal such queries can't be constructed within a pure sql-shell. Either use the boolean logic Bohemian and myself offered (and I still believe its exactly what you need) or you will need to let a "higher" logic (eg. stored procedure or any programming language) construct the query

Comment: @Sahal: Did you test this answer? It seems to be exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Hey @ypercube - I haven't forgotten about getting some examples together for that other question :)